# Excel VBA Sendkeys stops/pauses on the 2nd loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, internet-explorer, sendkeys

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewe7a.png)

I am filling the webform. and it requires a keyboard press. so I use sendkeys to hit tab. It works perfectly fine for the 1st time but when it loops 2nd time it stops/pauses at `Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True` . I have to click inside VBA then it resumes again.

Thank you.

For i = 2 To 3

```
IE.getElementsByName("recipientName")(0).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)

   AppActivate ("Internet Explorer"), True
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    For tabbtn = 1 To 20
        Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
     Next Tabbtb

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: TAB changes the focus. Can you tell us more about your project? Can you give us the url or at least the html code of the page?

Comment: Can you please inform us of the purpose of sending the tab key for 20 times? Do you just want to focus on any specific element on the page? If yes, then directly try to access the element using its ID or Name. It will be a better option. It can be possible that your code passing the tab key in the VBA editor. Please try to provide detailed information about the issue and your requirement along with VBA and HTML code samples. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi, I am new to this form. i have attached a screenshot of the webpage as you can see. using Excel VBA  i can send information to correct Element but when i click add it does not recognize the text inside. That's why I use TAB 20 to show that there is a text and it works.

Comment: The problem is that when it loop for 2nd time it stops/Pauses at Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True and does not carry on until i click inside VBA or click VBA window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to check that site and I understand that you are trying to add the value to the textbox but when you submit the data it shows that fields are required.

Passing the TAB key 20 times is not the correct solution for this issue.

You need to dispatch the event after setting the value in the field.

**Note:** You need to dispatch the event for each field in which you add the value.

I don't have access to that specific page so I made a test with their login page. The structure of the code will be the same throughout the site.

Here, I am just showing you the demo for how you need to dispatch the event for an element.

There are 2 textboxes. 1 Username 2 Password. I will only try to dispatch the event for Username. You can notice that It will not show the Required validation for Username but it will display the Required validation for the Password.

Sample code:

```
   Option Explicit

'It works with Excel 32 bit and Excel 64 bit
#If Win64 Then
  'For 64 bit systems
  Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
  'For 32 bit systems
 ' Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Sub test()

Dim url As String
Dim browser As Object
Dim btn As Object
Dim txt As Object
Dim psw As Object

  url = "https://www.myhermes.co.uk/login.html#/" 'Please modify the URL here...

  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  'Stop
  Set txt = browser.document.getElementById("existingUser") ' Please modify the ID of the element here...
  txt.Focus
  txt.Value = "abc@xyz.com"
  Set psw = browser.document.getElementById("existingPassword")
  psw.Value = "12345"
  Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, txt, "change")

   Set btn = browser.document.getElementById("loginButton") ' This is the demo submit button. You can modify this code as per your own requirements...
  btn.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

The similar thing you need to perform on the page you are entering the values to fix this issue. You can modify the code sample as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Can i get your contact email Please?

Comment: I am sorry to inform you that we are not allowed to share the Email ID. Whenever you have the IE automation related issue you can post on this forum with proper tags. Microsoft engineers will try to provide suggestions to solve that issue. Thanks for your understanding.